# How to include a dynamic page contents into a template?

Tags: python

I have to include a dynamic page content into my template, Say I have a left panel which gets the data dynamically through a view. Now, I have to include this left panel into all my pages but I do not want to duplicate the code for all the pages. Is there any way, I can write a single script and include it in all my templates to display the left panel in all my pages?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: do you use any specific framework? if so, please provide details ...

Comment: If you aren't using any libraries, you just have to return the reusable template as a string. If you are, then there are library-specific solutions.

Comment: I am using Django framework...

Answer (score 0):

What you trying to achieve is directly supported in pretty much all template languages I know of. I would strongly recommend using one the many good choices for Python:

- **[Genshi](http://genshi.edgewall.org/)**
- **[Kid](http://www.kid-templating.org/)**
- **[Jinja](http://jinja.pocoo.org/)**
- **[Mako](http://www.makotemplates.org/)**

If you were using **[Genshi](http://genshi.edgewall.org/)** for example (the default template language in **[TurboGears](http://www.turbogears.org)** web application framework) what you want to do would look something like this:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:py="http://genshi.edgewall.org/"
      xmlns:xi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XInclude"
      py:strip="">
  <xi:include href="header.html" />
  <xi:include href="sidebar.html" />
  <xi:include href="footer.html" />

  <!-- The rest of your page goes here -->
<html>
```

`header.html`, `sidebar.html` and `footer.html` need only be defined once and reused in any other page.

Comment: Thanks for your help Tendayi , your suggestion seems to work in case the contents are static i.e. for the html files. But in my case the the contents are generated dynamically as I mentioned and this would not work.