# whats the best way to parse and replace the string with its values?

Tags: python, templates, string-formatting, replace

I may have string like,

```
"""Hello, %(name)s,
how are you today, 
here is amount needed: %(partner_id.account_id.debit_amount)d
"""
```

what would be the best solution for such template may i need to combine regular expression and `eval`, input string may differ like `$partner_id.account_id.debit_amount$` - for the moment I've kept as python string format - just for testing.

Comment: I would recommend a templating engine rather than hand rolling your own code for this as discussed in this previous question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2839513/how-to-include-a-dynamic-page-contents-into-a-template

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are going to do sophisticated templating, you may consider using an advanced template engine like [Jinja](http://jinja.pocoo.org/). There are plenty others as well.

Answer (score 2):

Python implemented a new .format() method on strings in Python 2.6 and 3.0. Check out this PEP: http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3101/

It is more powerful and flexible than the % operator and built into python:

Here are some examples from the PEP:

```
"My name is {0}".format('Fred')
"My name is {0.name}".format(open('out.txt', 'w'))
"My name is {0[name]}".format({'name':'Fred'})
```

It may be enough for your needs, if not, look at a templating engine like Jinja as others mentioned.

Answer (score 1):

If you're looking for something simple, try looking at [Python's builtin Template.](http://docs.python.org/library/string.html#template-strings) I use it quite a bit for quick and easy templating without the overhead of installing additional packages.

There's also the new [format()](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#string-methods) method.

Comment: The favourite templating engine question has now been deleted :(

Comment: Thanks Ben for the heads up. I've deleted the link.